# SQL Database running to other computers

Tags: sql, entity-framework, ado.net, database-connection

I have question about Entity Framework projects or ADO.NET.

How can other users use my project without import SQL database? Is there any method to automatically create database/tables?

Could you please give hints or reference article or something like that.

Thanks,

Comment: Depends on which **concrete database** you're actually meaning when you say "SQL" (this is just a **query language** - not a database system). Please add a relevant tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can other users use my project without import SQL database?

If you have a project that is just starting a good choise is to use [`Code First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542.aspx). In this case every developer can use a local database.

> Is there any method to automatically create database/tables?

Here comes the good part of Code first - the database will be generated for you. Another thing that helps a lot, in my opinion, is the seeding of test data - [Use Code First Migrations to Seed the Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3).

Further reading: [`Migrations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use enbedded dbs like derby,h2 etc.